# Filtering out integers (indexes) from Arraylist

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an arraylist of different phrases such as, "protein", " protein kinase", "functional", "functional protein", "sox5", "il-6", Now, if I give a sentence as input, "functional protein kinase and il-6 and sox5", it must provide output as, "{functional protein} kinase and {il-6} and {sox5}". Every word in the sentence must be compared with the phrases.

The code that I have done returns me starting and ending indexes of different strings which are compared with the arraylist of different phrases. I need to filter out only the indexes which is largest and without any collisions. 
For e.g.
Input:

[0, 7][8, 22][8, 15] [36, 43] [23, 43] [20, 30]

Required output:

[0, 7] [8, 22] [23, 43]

Cases:

- Between [8, 22] and [8, 15], [8, 22] is the largest because 22-8 = 14 > 15-8 = 7, so [8,22] must be selected.
- Between [36, 43], [23, 43] and [20, 30], 36 lies in the range [23, 43] and 30 also lies in the range [23, 43] which is collision but among these collisions, [23, 43] is
  largest and must be selected.

What should I do in order to get the required output? (comparing criteria)

I have done,

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> ListOfList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
for(int a = 0; a<ListOfList.size();a++)
        {
            if(a == ListOfList.size()-1) break;
            for(int b = a+1; b<ListOfList.size();b++)
            {
                if((ListOfList.get(a).get(0) == ListOfList.get(b).get(0)) && (ListOfList.get(a).get(1) < ListOfList.get(b).get(1)))     
                {
                    startOffset = ListOfList.get(b).get(0);
                    endOffset =  ListOfList.get(b).get(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    startOffset = ListOfList.get(a).get(0);
                    endOffset =  ListOfList.get(a).get(1);
                }
            } 
        }
```

Comment: I have compared each index with every other indexes and made another arraylist but it is not working. The comparing is becoming more complex with each cases.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (rather than descriptions). 2) *"but it is not working"*  'Not working' is about as useful in explaining the problem as a screen-door on the ISS. What did you expect to happen?  What happened instead?

Comment: I find your terminology confusing. You call "index" both a number and a pair of numbers. You don't define "large" in a clear way either. It's difficult to help you when you seem to be also confused about the framing of your problem.

Comment: your criteria for selecting [23, 43] seem to me somewhat too complicated to put into a concise algorithm.

Comment: So you have a set of intervals, you want to group them into subsets consisting of overlapping intervals (where for instance if A overlaps B and B overlaps C, then A,B,and C are in one subset, even if A and C don't overlap), and then return the largest interval in each subset.  Is that an accurate summary?  Also, what do you want to do if two intervals are equally large?

Comment: @TimGoodman, Yes I need the largest one if they overlap and either one if two intervals are equally large.

Comment: @DenisTulskiy, This case is becoming quite complicated. So needed some help.

Comment: maybe if you could describe the problem in less abstract words, it would be easier for us to suggest a solution? What are these string, how would you use resulting pairs of indexes?

Comment: @DenisTulskiy For eg. I have an arraylist of different phrases such as, "protein", " protein kinase", "functional", "functional protein", "sox5", "il-6",

Now, if I give a sentence as input, "functional protein kinase and il-6 and sox5", it must provide output as, "{functional protein} kinase and {il-6} and {sox5}". Every word in the sentence must be compared with the phrases.

Comment: @najus: that's much better, please add it to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand your solution would be to group all pairs with intersecting indexes, and then just find the one with max length in each group. Here's some boilerplate code. Let me know if you need more clarification:

static class Pair {
        public int start, end;

```
    Pair(int start, int end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    public int weight() {
        return end - start;
    }

    public boolean contains(int point) {
        return start <= point && point <= end;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("[%d, %d]", start, end);
    }
}

static class Group {
    public List<Pair> pairs = new ArrayList<Pair>();
    public Pair maxWeight;

    Group(Pair start) {
        add(start);
    }

    Group(List<Pair> pairs) {
        for (Pair pair : pairs) {
            add(pair);
        }
    }

    public boolean contains(Pair pair) {
        for (Pair my : pairs) {
            if (my.contains(pair.start) || my.contains(pair.end))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void add(Pair pair) {
        pairs.add(pair);
        if (maxWeight == null || maxWeight.weight() < pair.weight())
            maxWeight = pair;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Pair> pairs = new ArrayList<Pair>();
    pairs.add(new Pair(0, 7));
    pairs.add(new Pair(8, 15));
    pairs.add(new Pair(8, 22));
    pairs.add(new Pair(36, 43));
    pairs.add(new Pair(23, 43));
    pairs.add(new Pair(20, 30));
    List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<Group>();

    for (Pair pair : pairs) {
        List<Group> intersects = new ArrayList<Group>();
        for (Group group : groups) {
            if (group.contains(pair)) {
                intersects.add(group);
            }
        }

        if (intersects.isEmpty()) {
            groups.add(new Group(pair));
        } else {
            List<Pair> intervals = new ArrayList<Pair>();
            intervals.add(pair);
            for (Group intersect : intersects) {
                intervals.addAll(intersect.pairs);
            }

            groups.removeAll(intersects);
            groups.add(new Group(intervals));
        }
    }

    for (Group group : groups) {
        System.out.println(group.maxWeight);
    }
}
```

Comment: Denis, Would you please briefly explain it with one example?

Comment: @najus: just like in the example you gave in the question: [0, 7] will be in its own group, [8, 15] and [8, 22] in the second, and [36, 43] [23, 43] [20, 30] in the third. Do you need help implementing the `contains` method? It should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: Ok, I am trying to implement it. I might be needing help for contains method too.

Comment: Also, I have used ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> ListOfList for start and end indexes.

Comment: @najus: yeah, list of list looks really messy, small classes are much more informative and cleaner.

Comment: Denis, how would I add pairs? and please help on contains method?

Comment: @najus: I edited my answer with full solution

Comment: Denis, Take a look with these examples. 
          pairs.add(new Pair(11, 18));  
   pairs.add(new Pair(35, 42));  
   pairs.add(new Pair(11, 25));  
   pairs.add(new Pair(11, 42));  
   pairs.add(new Pair(0, 10));     
          pairs.add(new Pair(0, 18));  

It should have provided only [11, 42].

Comment: @najus: contains for Pair should be `start <= point && point <= end`, I got it wrong

Comment: No, it doesn't work for both cases. :(

Comment: @najus: ok, now it becomes hackish. I updated the code to merge if some pair intersects two groups. only now it gives ([0, 7],[23, 43]) because [20, 30] intersects [8, 22].

Comment: Thanks for the help. Any problem and i will buzz you. ;)

Comment: Denis, theres some problem. If I give pairs.add(new Pair(35, 43));
pairs.add(new Pair(0, 63));, the collision problem doesn't sort out.

Comment: @najus: you probably need to use some more complicated data structure like intersection trees. or just add in Group.contains a check that the pair contains some of my pairs.

Comment: It is becoming quite complex and I am looking for alternative ways of implementing Boyer Moore string search algorithm. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If i may suggest a diferent methodology to this problem, since you are working with words if i were you i would not work with indices but with the actual words.

test the first word and see if it in the list of phrases, if its not remove it from the test queue, if it is add the next word to the test and test it again continue this way until you dont find a match, once this process is complete then you have your first phrase match.

using your example

"functional protein kinase and il-6 and sox5" is the test queue and the result is empty.

first test would be "functional" which will return true, this means we need to add the next word and test again

second test would be "functional protein" which will return true so we need to add the word

third test would be "functional protein kinsae" which will return false, now we mark the previous test as a success and move it from the queue to the result, so we have

"{functional protein}" in the result and "kinase and il-6 and sox5" in the queue

next test would be "kinase" which is fasle so we move "kinase" from the queue to the result and now we have

"{functional protein} kinase" in the result and "and il-6 and sox5" in the queue

keep this going till the queue is empty.

i realize this is not a direct answer to your question but maybe a diferent way of looking at this problem will be of help to you.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I have already implemented this logic. It works for this case but not all. If I have additional phrases such as "protein kinase a anchor protein" in the given arraylist and if I give a sentence as, "functional protein kinase a anchor protein", then I should get output as "functional {protein kinase a anchor protein}" rather than "{functional protein} kinase a anchor protein", because it is longer.

Comment: yes you are correct this method is not perfect, i have had a similar problem myself in the past and i decided that a solution similar to this was good enough for my needs. just a friendly suggestion; you should think now how to handle panctuation marks as it caused me a lot of problems